# Cannot Start Rails 4: No support for Active Record version 42

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, unicorn

Started a separate Rails project intended to use version 4 and upgraded relative gems. But these all break w/ warning: "No support for Active Record version 42" when trying to start server (rails s), console (rails c) and starting a Unicorn with it.  To avoid any conflict w/ previous project that used Rails 3, I've already installed gems on a different version of Ruby + rvm, so started out clean (or uninstalled all).

Is this a gems library conflict or certain gems related to Rails 4 are incompatible?

Here are my Gemfile and Gemfile.lock files:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9mqbmloie0r99d9/Gemfile?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/rg7wf9ydjv4hncl/Gemfile.lock?dl=0

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by *'these all break w/ warning: "No support for Active Record version 42"'*? What does the warning actually say? Show the exact error message, not a summarised/rephrased version. Please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51181158/edit).

Comment: And rather than seeing a list of all gems like that, can you instead post the `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`? Doing this should hopefully allow us to **reproduce** the error - which makes it a million times easier for someone to confidently answer the question accurately.